# Overlay Panel when image mouse hover

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Twitter Bootstrap and I want to implement a overlay panel when mouse hover the img tag, like in Stackoverflow when details is showed when the focus is in the image of the user.

This image illustrate:

[image]

Someone how I do this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whatever you want as the "hovering" object, just give `position: absolute`, then have a `:hover` selector, for example:

**HTML**

```
<div>
   <div class="Profile">
       Basic Profile
       <div class="Overlay">
           Put overlay stuff here.
       </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.Profile{
    position: relative;
}
.Overlay{
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0px;
    opacity: 0;
    height: 0;
}

.Profile:hover .Overlay{
    height: auto;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

So now, when a user hovers over the `.Profile` div, the `.Overlay` contained within it will appear, then add any additional styling for transitions and making it pretty.

[Example JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c780pp2g/)